# CSS Dropdown menu is waiting for a click on the item and then the hover works

Tags: html, css

My CSS Dropdown menu by hover is only working after the user clicks on the option, right after the click the dropdown shows and when hovering  its acts perfectly,
I can't figure why it is happen and how to make the hover not wait for a click,

heres the html code:

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item">events</a>
  <div class="nav-content">
    <div class="nav-sub">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-item">weddings</a>     
          <div class="underline"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-item">parties</a>
          <div class="underline"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-item">birthdays</a>
          <div class="underline"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

heres the related css:

```css
    .nav-item {
        display: inline-block;   
        padding:  20px, 30px;
        height:  0px;
        width: 130px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
         border-color: black;
        line-height: 40px;
    }


    .nav-content{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        border-color: black;
        color: #000000; font-family: "Varela Round";
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 24px;
        text-align: right;
        list-style-type: none;
        z-index: 99999;
        display: none;
        left: 1110px;
    }

    .nav-sub{    
        padding: 1px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }


    .nav-sub ul li:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }

    .nav-sub ul li:hover > .nav-item{
        color: white;
    }

    .nav-item:focus{
        background-color:whitesmoke;
    }

    .nav-item:hover ~ .nav-content{
        display: block;

    }
    .nav-content:hover{
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your code here is pretty solid for a drop-down nav menu. It also works, as is,  on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5efz2rs/1/). If it is not showing up until you click, some of your other code (not posted) is interfering. You might have to post the rest of your code in order to get help figuring out what is causing that behavior.

**Note:**

You will notice that positioning will be a chore unless you make a couple of changes. This is because positioning absolutely with relation to the window generally causes nothing but trouble.

```css
    /* Makes absolute children relative to the container */
    li { 
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav-content {
        ...
        left: 0;
        ...
    }
```

The fiddle shows the changes, simply because it was otherwise causing inaccessible demonstration.